# Which is a better top level container for this design, JFrame with Jpanels, or JDesktop with JInternalFrames

Tags: java, swing, awt, java-2d

I'm a beginner with Swing and AWT, I'm looking to build a GUI using Netbeans.  My GUI requires three areas, that I'm currently thinking of as JPanels on a JFrame.  I require a "Drawing" panel that will listen for mouse input and draw Java2D shapes.  The drawing panel will be anchored to the top left.  The other two areas are a "Properties" scroll pane, and a "Controller" scroll pane.  The controller pane will determine which drawn elements will be displayed via buttons, and the properties scroll pane will show details about any shape object that is clicked in the drawing pane (endpoints, color, etc..).

A typical use case for the drawing area is such that the first click in the drawing area will be the first set of co-ordinates for a shape, IE: a line.  That click will be captured as a point2d object.  The second click will be the second point2D object, and a line will be built between the two.  The controller area will have buttons like "Circle" "Line" "Elipse", etc.  Depending on which controller button is clicked, only shapes of that type will be drawn in the drawing area.  The controller and properties scroll panes will not be moveable, they will be locked and resizable to the bottom and right sides of the GUI, respectively.

As a beginner, I'm struggling with the best components to use.  I've been reading up on JDesktop and JInternalFrame, but it seems like I don't really need all that.  A simple JFrame with three JPanels should suffice, right?  More specifically, I think I need a top level JFrame, with a JPanel for the drawing frame and two JScrollPanels.  I'll need a mouse listener on the drawing pane to capture the co-ordinates of each click, and listeners for each button in the control pane.  Can I put a mouse listener on a JPanel, and draw Java2D shapes to it, or will I need a different (better?) container inside the JPanel to do my drawing?

Comment: I'd love to see what refactoring for brevity would do to this post.  I bet you can properly express your question in 50% of the space.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive criticism, as a beginner I'm learning all this.  Maybe after I've learned everything I need to know, I can "refactor for brevity".  Of course, once I've learned it all, the question itself is moot.

Comment: +1 for positive response to constructive criticism.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32997/156102

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`GraphPanel`](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel) may give you some ideas for constructing such an application. "It features moveable, resizable, colored nodes connected by edges."

[image: GraphPanel]

Comment: I like this, thanks for the link I'll look through the source for some ideas on how to make this happen.

Comment: Also consider `JToolBar` for the control panel.

Answer (score 4):

JInternalFrames typically have titlebars, go-away boxes etc. [example here](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JInternalFrame.html) which doesn't seem to fit your model.  (Unless you want users to be able to move the panels anywhere they want, or make them go away?)  So I'd suggest the simpler JFrame with JPanels.

Comment: I don't actually need the users to re-arrange the interface.  Actually, for now, I specifically don't want them to be able to.  Google actually gave me that example, but I wasn't sure how relevant it was.  On your recommendation, I'll take a closer look.  Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want them to rearrange, definitely avoid JInternalFrames.    As I suggested, use a JFrame with JPanels.  @Mike Clark has a nice example in his answer.

Answer (score 4):

Consider two JSplitPanes to separate the drawing area, control area, and properties area.  JSplitPane allows the user to resize the areas by clicking and dragging the split line with the mouse.

[image]

(Use a JFrame for the top level component.)

As a beginner, if you don't need resizing and scrolling, you will have a much easier time if you make an app that doesn't resize or scroll.

Comment: Interesting, looks like I should read up/practice with split panes a bit to see if they will be useful for my project.  for Split pane 2, will the control and property areas scroll, or do I need to nest a scroll pane inside each pane?  Also - Will I need some additional component nested inside the drawing area or will I be able to listen and draw in that pane directly?

Comment: @NickAbbey you probably want scrollpanes in all three areas.

Comment: You will probably want to put JScrollPanes inside each of the three logical areas.  You could then add your widget-containing JPanels (and one e.g. GraphPanel) to the JScrollPanes.  If you don't need resizing and scrolling, you will have a much easier time if you make an app that doesn't resize or scroll.

Comment: I was actually just thinking that doing away with resizing is probably a good move (for now) but I think that the control and property areas will have to scroll because all the elements won't fit.  I've already got a quick wireframe up using split panes and I'm liking how it works so far.  I'm going to run through the split pane tutorial at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html and will probably end up using this design.