# How to move shapes in JPanel by clicking-and-dragging

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

So, I have this simple program that allows you to click a JMenu item "New Rectangle" and it adds a shape on the center of the screen. My question is: how can I click-and-drag this around the window? I know I will need some type of Mouse Listener but I'm not sure exactly how to implement it.

```
public class SimpleDraw {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new UMLWindow();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(30, 30, 1000, 700);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // Display the window.
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}

class UMLWindow extends JFrame {
    Squares squares = new Squares();

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public UMLWindow() {
        addMenus();
    }

    public void addMenus() {

        getContentPane().add(squares);

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu shapes = new JMenu("Shapes");

        JMenuItem rectangleMenuItem = new JMenuItem("New Rectangle");
        rectangleMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                squares.addSquare(10, 10, 100, 100);
            }
        });

        shapes.add(rectangleMenuItem);

        menubar.add(shapes);

        setJMenuBar(menubar);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}

class Squares extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<Rectangle> squares = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();

    public void addSquare(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(getWidth() / 2 - width / 2, getHeight()
                / 2 - height / 2, width, height);
        squares.add(rect);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setOpaque(true);
        this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        for (Rectangle rect : squares) {
            g2.draw(rect);
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: One way is to use an AffineTransform to translate a Shape object as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22595225/522444).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html

Comment: You'll need a MouseListener and a MouseMotionListener

Comment: A complete example is cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11002950/230513).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can help you : 
http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/resizablecomponent/

Disadvantage of code

In this code we do not layout manager. So if we have a component in center of jframe when this jframe is re-sizing this component maybe display in corner of jframe. You can solve this problem but it is a little complex. We can talk about this problem if you want.

Comment: This seems like it is for resizing. I am not looking to resize. I want to click and crack the entire object to another place on the window (but it will remain the same size)

Comment: Yes , this code has support these facilities : drag and drop the component in another place and re-sizing this component. In fact  it has an extra feature. If you do not need this re-sizing feature , we can edit Resizable class and we have just this case :         case Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR: . I do not know it can help you to have your pleasant code or not.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [solution for this in this package here](http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/shape/). You can see that there is an AreaDragger class, which sounds like what you are looking for